Unable to use system-assigned identity with Knex: ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''
I'm encountering an issue while trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database using Knex with system-assigned identity. Despite configuring Knex to utilize system-assigned identity for authentication, I'm receiving the following error:
ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.
at ConnectionError (/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:13:12)
at Parser.<anonymous> (/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1194:51)
at Parser.emit (node:events:517:28)
at Readable.<anonymous> (/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:27:14)
at Readable.emit (node:events:517:28)
at addChunk (node
/streams/readable:368:12)
at readableAddChunk (node
/streams/readable:341:9)
at Readable.push (node
/streams/readable:278:10)
at next (node
/streams/from:98:31)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node
/process/task_queues:95:5)
Here's a summary of my setup:

I'm using Knex to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database.
I've configured Knex to use system-assigned identity for authentication.
The code is running in an environment where system-assigned identity is enabled and configured.
Despite correct configuration, I'm encountering a login failure with an empty user.

Here's a simplified version of my code:
This is the configuration we are using for connecting
dbConfig = {
  client: config.ENV.TNT_DB_CLIENT,
  connection: {
    server: config.ENV.TNT_DB_SERVER,
    authentication: {
    type: 'azure-active-directory-msi-app-service',
    options: {
        tenantId: config.ENV.AZURE_TENANT_ID
        }
    },
    options: {
       database: config.ENV.TNT_DATABASE,
       trustServerCertificate: false,
       encrypt: true,
       requestTimeout: 300000
     }
    },
  plugins: [knexPlugin()],
  pool: {
      acquireTimeoutMillis: 300000,
      min: parseInt(config.ENV.TNT_DB_MIN_CONNECTION),
      max: parseInt(config.ENV.TNT_DB_MAX_CONNECTION)
     },
 migrations: {
    tableName: 'knex_migrations'
   },
  requestTimeout: 300000,
  connectionTimeout: 300000,
  acquireConnectionTimeout: 300000
 };



ConnectionError: Login failed for user ' '. at ConnectionError (/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:13:12) at Parser.

The above error says there is no user specified in the attempt to authenticate to the SQL Server which is expected if using a system-assigned managed identity for authentication. Try with the below code it runs successfully after creating an user and the method credential.getToken is used to get an access token from Azure Active Directory for the specified resource. The token is used for authenticating against the Azure SQL Database.
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require('@azure/identity');
const knex = require('knex');

async function getKnexConfig() {
  const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  const tokenResponse = await credential.getToken("https://database.windows.net/");

  return {
    client: 'mssql',
    connection: {
      server: '<server_name>',
      database: '<database_name>',
      options: {
        encrypt: true,
        enableArithAbort: true,
        token: tokenResponse.token,
      },
    },
  };
}

async function initializeKnex() {
  const config = await getKnexConfig();
  const db = knex(config);

  db.raw('SELECT 1')
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to the database'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Connection failed:', err));

  return db;
}

initializeKnex();

Output:
Connected to the database


Could you try with the above code once and let me know if you are facing any errors.
